# What do I put in these template arguments for this function call?

Tags: c++, templates

I was wondering how I could make this function call, I mean the third example where the functions can't decay to function pointers?

```
class SimpleClass 
{public:
    SimpleClass(int i, float f, const char* c) {}
};

template <typename TGet, typename TSet>
class TemplatedClass
{public:
    TemplatedClass(int i, float f, TGet getter, TSet setter, const char* name) {}
};


class Creator
{public:
    template <typename T, typename ... TArgs>
    static T* create(int i, float f, TArgs ... args)
    {
        return new T(i, f, args...);
    }

};

int main()
{
    Creator::create<SimpleClass>(7, 0.f, "Name"); // WORKS
    
    Creator::create<TemplatedClass< const char* (*)(), void (*)() >>(
        7,
        0.f,
        []() { return "Called Getter"; },
        []() { std::cout << "Called Setter"; },
        "Name"); // WORKS
    
    int captureMe = 3;

    Creator::create<TemplatedClass< ? , ? >>(
        7,
        0.f,
        []() { return captureMe; },
        []() { std::cout << captureMe; },
        "Name"); // ???    
}
```

Comment: Is this because you need to include `captureMe` in the lambda declaration? If so that can't be a simple function pointer, it's going to have contextual information that precludes it from being one. Why not use lambda types instead or `std::function`?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, your lambdas are capturing `captureMe`, so you need to specify a default capture mode or capture it yourself. For instance, `[&]` instead of `[]`.

Then, if you save the lambdas into a variable like:

```
const auto x = [&]() { return captureMe; };
const auto y = [&]() { std::cout << captureMe; };
```

You can then refer to their type using `decltype`:

```
Creator::create<TemplatedClass<decltype(x), decltype(y)>>(
    7,
    0.f,
    x,
    y,
    "Name");
```

Answer (score 1):

CTAD in C++17 can make it easier:

```cpp
class Creator
{
public:
    template <template<typename...>class T, typename ... TArgs>
    static auto create(int i, float f, TArgs ... args)
    {
        return new T(i, f, args...);
    }
    template <typename T, typename ... TArgs>
    static T* create(int i, float f, TArgs ... args)
    {
        return new T(i, f, args...);
    }

};

int main(){
    Creator::create<TemplatedClass>( // just template name
        7,
        0.f,
        [&captureMe]() { return captureMe; },
        [&captureMe]() { std::cout << captureMe; },
        "Name"); // ok   
}
```

in this case, you needn't to provide the template arguments at all.